# ASP.NET MVC: Ignore custom attribute in a base controller class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, inheritance, custom-attributes, base-class

I have a number of Controllers in my project that all inherit from a controller I've named BaseController. I wrote a custom attribute that I applied to the entire BaseController class, so that each time an action runs in any of my controllers, that attribute will run first.

The problem is that I have a couple of controller actions that I'd like to ignore that attribute, but I don't know how to do it.

Can anyone help? I'm using MVC 1.

Thanks.

Comment: can you post your attribute? does it prevent the action from getting hit?

Comment: i'd rather not post the attribute for proprietary data reasons, but yes, it may redirect the user to the login page rather than allow the action to be hit.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had a similar need for something like this and found that by creating an authorization filter (implementing/deriving from `FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter`) rather than a regular action filter (deriving from `ActionFilterAttribute`), and setting `Inherited=true` and `AllowMultiple=false` on the attribute, that it would only run once at the appropriate spot.

This means I am able to "cascade" my filter down from a base controller (the site-wide default), to a derived controller (for example the AdminController or whatever), or even further down to an individual action method.

For example,

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class|AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited=true, AllowMultiple=false)]
public class MyCustomAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    private MyCustomMode _Mode;
    public MyCustomAttribute(MyCustomMode mode)
    {
        _Mode = mode;
    }
    public virtual void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");
        }
        // run my own logic here.
        // set the filterContext.Result to anything non-null (such as
        // a RedirectResult?) to skip the action method's execution.
        //
        //
    }
}

public enum MyCustomMode
{
    Enforce,
    Ignore
}
```

And then to use it, I can apply it to my super-controller,

```
[MyCustomAttribute(Ignore)]
public class BaseController : Controller
{
}
```

And I can change/override it for specific controllers, or even for specific actions!

```
[MyCustomAttribute(Enforce)]
public class AdministrationController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
    }

    [MyCustomAttribute(Ignore)] 
    public ActionResult SomeBasicPageSuchAsAHelpDocument()
    {
    }
}
```

This allowed me to "turn off" the filter for specific cases, while still being able to apply it as a default on either the whole controller or whole application.

Good luck!

Comment: This looks promising. I'm going to revise the way I did it before and get back to you with my results.

Comment: For posterity: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/857142/mvc-attributes-on-controllers-and-actions/15261325#15261325

Answer (score 12):

In your custom attribute, you can add this ShouldRun() check like this:

```
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (ShouldRun(filterContext))
        {
            // proceed with your code
        }
    }

    private bool ShouldRun(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var ignoreAttributes = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(IgnoreMyCustomAttribute), false);
        if (ignoreAttributes.Length > 0)
            return false;

        return true;
    }
```

ShouldRun() simply checks whether there's a "IgnoreMyCustomAttribute" on your action.  If it's there, then your custom attribute won't do anything.

You'll now want to create a simple IgnoreMyCustomAttribute, which doesn't do anything:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class IgnoreMyCustomAttribute: ActionFilterAttribute
{
}
```

Whenever you decorate your controller action with [IgnoreMyCustom], then MyCustomAttribute won't do anything. e.g.:

```
[IgnoreMyCustom]
public ViewResult MyAction() {
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure there is an easy way to remove attributes in this situation. But I have done something similar for a project and what I did, as it was only in a few instances I didn't want my attribute to run, was to create two attributes.

My first attribute was applied to my base controller as you've done but it was aware of the existance of a second attribute and by implementing that second attribute I could disable the attribute on the base class from running.

Not sure if it was the best solution but it worked for me.

This was applied to the base controller:

```
/// <summary>
/// This is used to force the schema to HTTP is it is HTTPS.
/// RequireHttpsAttribute or OptionalHttpsAttribute takes precedence if used.
/// </summary>
public class RequireHttpAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public virtual void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");

        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsSecureConnection)
        {
            object[] attributes = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(true);
            if (!attributes.Any(a => a is RequireHttpsAttribute || a is OptionalHttpsAttribute))
            {
                HandleHttpsRequest(filterContext);
            }
        }
    }

    protected virtual void HandleHttpsRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        //  only redirect for GET method, otherwise browser may not propogate the verb and request body correctly
        if (!string.Equals(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod, "GET", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            throw new InvalidOperationException(MvcResources.RequireHttpAttribute_MustNotUseSsl);

        //  redirect to HTTP version
        string url = "http://" + filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Host + filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl;
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(url);
    }
}
```

Like so:

```
[RequireHttp]
public abstract class Controller : System.Web.Mvc.Controller
{
}
```

I could then use what is effectively a dummy attribute to disable it.

```
/// <summary>
/// This attribute allows the action to be server on HTTP and HTTPS but neither is enforce.
/// RequireHttpsAttribute takes precedence if used.
/// </summary>
public class OptionalHttpsAttribute : FilterAttribute
{
    // This is deliberately empty, the attribute is used by RequireHttpAttribute to stop it changing schema to HTTP
}
```

Like so:

```
    [OptionalHttps]
    public ActionResult OptionalHttps()
    {
        return View();
    }
```