# Making a controller not visible to the client in ASP.NET WEB API (or MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

Let's suppose I have a layer of abstract controllers, which delegates the request to its child controller class, until it reaches the implementation.

Think of it like a pipeline of controllers, that the request must go through, and includes caching the responses, authorizing and authenticating the user, validating the input and output data, handling repository access, etc.

My ***leaf*** class (the last child of the hierarchy), may have the following signature:

```
public class SeasonsController : DefaultPersistenceRestController
                                 <int, Season, SeasonPutDTO, SeasonPostDTO, SeasonQueryData> {
      /** Controller implementation here  **/
}
```

The base classes have a lot of reusable code located in one module, this is good and has helped me a lot when changing the logic of my controllers at a global level.

Now, suppose `SeasonsController` need to call `EpisodesController`, for irrelevant reasons.

The call would be like this:

```
EpisodesController episodeController = new EpisodesController();
//Do something with EpisodesController
```

The problem is that I don't want `EpisodesController` to be accessed from the outside, such as client's request. ASP.NET automatically identifies controllers and creates a public endpoint for them, such as `http://localhost:80/episodes`.

I created `EpisodesController` because it uses a lot of logic from the controller's base classes, but I intend to use it internally.

I can desactivate authentication, authorization, cache and all other stuff that will be useless if a controller is used in this way, so that's not a problem.

However, I cannot manage to prevent ASP.NET to ignore my `EpisodesController` class, and to not consider it like a controller.

Is there an attribute or annotation maybe that will tell the compiler to do this? Maybe some modification in **Web.config**?.

Also note that I don't want to change `EpisodesController`'s class name to another name, as it is really a controller, but an internal one.

Comment: If you want to prevent actions being invoked, why not make them non public? or if they must be public, maybe try something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390541/asp-net-mvc-ignore-custom-attribute-in-a-base-controller-class

Comment: why does it need to be a controller if it is going to be private?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to use the [IgnoreRoute](http://www.strathweb.com/2014/04/ignoring-routes-asp-net-web-api/) extension method. Or you could try the `internal` as suggested by beautifulcoder. If it's in another assembly (and you can modify it) you could also make it visible to other assemblies with [InternalsVisibleToAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Although to be honest, using one controller within another controller doesn't seem right to me. I would try and refactor you common functionality to services/helpers, then you could probably also make your `EpisodesController` into a simple service. Composition over inheritance and all that :)

Comment: Can you please assist in this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43002283/how-to-allow-internal-mvc-web-api-from-external-site-outside-the-network

Answer (score 1):

If you make a controller `public` it will be accessible. From what I understand, you can change it to `protected` or `internal`.

Comment: What if the controller is in another assembly?

Comment: It might be a good idea to move it to the same assembly. You may also try `protected internal`