# Remove all action filter attributes in a derived web api controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have a simple web api controller where action methods are decorated with various built in and custom filters.Now I want to create another controller which inherits from the first one, how can I remove\bypass all the action filters on the derived controller?

**Base controller:**

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/values
    [Authorize]
    [CustomFilter]
    public virtual IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

**Derived controller:**

```
public class ExtenderController : ValuesController
{
    //Must bypass [Authorize] and [CustomFilter]
    public override IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return base.Get();
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot. do this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390541/asp-net-mvc-ignore-custom-attribute-in-a-base-controller-class

Answer (score 0):

Decorate your Action or Controller with **[OverrideActionFilters]**

Answer (score 0):

**Derived controller:**

```
public class ExtenderController : ValuesController
{
    [OverrideAuthorization] //Bypass [Authorize] (Bypass IAuthorizationFilter)
    [OverrideActionFilters] //Bypass [CustomFilter] if inherited from IActionFilter. If not, write your own bypass filter. See an example at link (1) below
    public override IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return base.Get();
    }
}
```

see [link(1)](http://shaktitanwar.com/asp-net-mvc-5-override-filters/) and [link(2)](https://www.learnmvc.in/aspnet-mvc5-filter-overrides.php) for details